# spatialite geometry vs PostGIS geography

Tags: postgis, spatialite

When I worked with PostGIS I used [geography type](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography) for geo objects with gps coordinates like latitude and longitude on the WGS-84 ellipsoid.
Now I have to use SQLite and [libspatialite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index) correspondingly.
I wonder, if I create column like this:

```
Select AddGeometryColumn ('my_table', 'Geometry', 4326, 'POINT', 2)
```

will queries with `ST_Within/ST_Contains(geo_rect, my_table.geometry)` find suitable
points if `geo_rect` covers north pole, or 0,180 longitude?

here how it works in postgis:

```
    geo_demo=# select ST_DWithin(ST_GeographyFromText('POLYGON((-179 53, 179 53, 179 50, -179 50, -179 53))'),  ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(-179 61)'), 1.0, true);
 st_dwithin 
------------
 f
(1 row)

geo_demo=# select ST_DWithin(ST_GeographyFromText('POLYGON((-179 53, 179 53, 179 50, -179 50, -179 53))'),  ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(-179 51)'), 1.0, true);
 st_dwithin 
------------
 t
(1 row)

geo_demo=#
```

as you see point with latitude 51,-179.5 inside geo box:

```
53, -179 <-> 53,179
50, -179 <->  50,179
```

but

```
spatialite> select Within(MakePoint(-179.5, 51, 4326), PolyFromText('POLYGON((-179 53, 179 53, 179 50, -179 50, -179 53))', 4326));
0
```

gives 0, but really point inside geo box.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to include what you have tried, and what error(s) you have encountered. "Will this product work for me?" is quite broad and may be dependent on what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @Vince I add sql quires to make my question is more clear.

Comment: The st_dwithin you specified is true if the point is within 1 degree of the poly. Which is true. But it isn't inside the poly, which you are checking in spatialite.

Comment: @LennertDeFeyter Why it is not in poly? `50 < 51 < 53` and longitude `-179.5` lay between `-179` and  `179`

Comment: @LennertDeFeyter and `st_dwithin` for geography type take `distance_meters` not in degrees, see https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The geometry model of SpatiaLite assumes a flat Cartesian plane. From 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/5HLZIXzGxQ0

> e.g. a LINESTRING(179.9999 0, -179.9999 0) doesn't cross at all the
>   dateline: it simply goes westward for about 359.99 degrees along the
>   equator.
>
> So, each time you have to represent some geometry crossing the
>   dateline you are always required to split such geometry in two halves:
>   one laying at extreme right, the other at extreme left.

There is another thing in your example that adds confusion. The point `MakePoint(-179, 51, 4326))` is on top of the outline of `POLYGON((-179 53, 179 53, 179 50, -179 50, -179 53))` and therefore is is not within (totally inside) the polygon https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html so SpatiaLite gives correct answer. The equivalent of ST_DWithin in SpatiaLite is "PtDistWithin" http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

Comment: I changed to `MakePoint(-179.5, 51, 4326)`, but it still gives 0 instead of 1

Comment: No wonder because now the point is totally outside your polygon - to the left of the leftmost border. It seems that you did the same wrong thinking even before when you wrote `longitude -179.5 lay between -179 and 179`. Your polygon does not cross the dateline.

Comment: I completely not understand you, why `-179.5` not lay between `-179` and `179`? `-180` = `180`, so we get sequence `-179`, `-179.5`, `-180`=`180`, `179.5`, `179`, where is mistake here?

Comment: For SpatiaLite -180 != 180. As SpatiaLite geometry your polygon is located between -179 and +179 degrees and -179.5 is less than -179. PostGIS geography goes always the shortest route, see 4.2.3. Geography Advanced FAQ in http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch04.html.

Comment: but what the point then in `spatialite` if it can not handle corner cases like poles and `180` longitude? Without this functionality it is the same as `sqlite` `rtree`?

Comment: You must split the geometries which go across the dateline https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/5HLZIXzGxQ0. Corner cases are corner cases, SpatiaLite as well as PostGIS geometry work fine without workarounds when you do not deal with the corner cases.

Comment: But if I have to deal with globe by my self, and `spatialite` can handle only plane, then I can just drop `spatialite` and use only `sqlite`, because of `sqlite` provides the same functionality for search point inside gbox, but without need one more library. Thanks, for answers. I accept answer, if you add comment about dateline to answer, because of it was the main question.